Must 127.0.0.1 be belong to an interface/adapter?
The route table on my PC is like:
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2   4060
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    202.212.131.53     32
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link        172.19.0.1      0
   202.212.131.53  255.255.255.255         On-link    202.212.131.53    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556

Note that the line "127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556"
seems to say there is an interface with the IP address 127.0.0.1. But using the "ipconfig /all" command, I cannot find any network adapter(physical or virtual) that has the ip address 127.0.0.1. So, I wonder what that line means. To what interface does it send packets with the Network Destination 127.0.x.x?

yes 127.0.0.0/8 must only be used on a loopback adapter, but loopback adapters are not displayed in ipconfig, since no one ever wants to see them. In prior versions of windows, you might have to install it (win 9x/NT4) and in XP and I think Vista/Win7 you could see the adapter, and the device in device manager, but nowadays they hide it more or less completely.

BTW, 127.0.0.1 through 127.0.0.255 are all loop-back, an never leave the NIC. They are distinct, though, so one can have two servers with IP 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 and they can be addressed separately, on that PC.


Must 127.0.0.1 be belong to an interface/adapter?

It's not mandatory (an IP stack could handle it in whichever way it likes), but generally it is simpler to have it assigned to a virtual interface – this leads to fewer special cases in the IP code. So on most of the general-purpose operating systems it indeed belongs to a virtual "Loopback" or lo interface.

Note that the line "127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 4556" seems to say there is an interface with the IP address 127.0.0.1. But using the "ipconfig /all" command, I cannot find any network adapter(physical or virtual) that has the ip address 127.0.0.1

There is one; it's just hidden from ipconfig. But the interface list at the very top of route print shows it under the name of "Software Loopback Interface".

No, 127.0.0.1 does not need to belong to an interface/adapter. It depends on the developers of the implementation of IP on that platform how they represent special routes such as 127.0.0.0/8.
May I illustrate that by explaining what a null route is?
It is a route that is configured so any traffic destined for it is not forwarded.

On Cisco platforms, the user specifies the Null interface as the outgoing interface.
On Juniper platforms, the user specifies the discard or reject action in the context of a routing policy.
On Linux, the user specifies a route with the blackhole keyword.

That's three ways of configuring the same function.
